# update multiple fields from select with group by

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have a

table A

```
(A_pkey,B_pkey,A_type,A_value)
```

and a table B

```
(B_pkey, B_minValueForTypeX,B_maxValueTypeX,B_minValueForTypeY,B_maxValuForeTypeY,B_minValueForTypeZ,B_maxValueForTypeZ)
```

with following values:

### A

```
1,1,'X',100

2,1,'X',1000

3,1,'X',300

4,1,'Y',500

5,1,'Y',200

6,1,'Z',300

7,2,'X',100

8,2,'X',200

9,2,'X',300

10,2,'Y',100

11,2,'Y',2000
```

### B

```
1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL

2,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

is it possible in one single query to update B so that

```
B_minValueForTypeX= min(A_value) from A where A_type='X' (with A.B_pkey=B.B_pkey)
B_maxValueForTypeX= max(A_value) from A where A_type='X' (with A.B_pkey=B.B_pkey)
B_minValueForTypeY= min(A_value) from A where A_type='Y' (with A.B_pkey=B.B_pkey)
```

and so on...

so that table B ends up like that

```
1,100,1000,200,500,300,300

2,100,300,100,2000,0,0
```

I'm sure it can be done but didn't figure out how.

Could someone help me on this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte (key, value1, value2, value3, value4...)
(
SELECT B_pkey, 
MIN(CASE WHEN A_type = 'x' then A_value else null end), 
max(CASE WHEN    A_type = 'x' then A_value else null end), 
MIN(CASE WHEN A_type = 'y' then A_value else null        end), 
max(CASE WHEN A_type = 'y' then value3 else null end),
.
.
.
FROM A
GROUP BY B_pkey
)
update b
set B_minValueForTypeX = cte.value1,
B_maxValueTypeX = cte.value2, 
B_minValueForTypeY = cte.value3,
B_maxValuForeTypeY = cte.value4,
.
.
.
from b
inner join cte on
b.B_pkey= cte.B_pkey
```

Comment: Hi chris, sorry to ask, but could you please write the exact complete query with fields named as above?...very sorry to ask...